# While scrolling, The current div goes up, and another div under it (under the first div background) shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have unordered list contains two list items. Every list item has content that fill a page height. So this means that the whole web page contains two scrollable pages.

```html
<ul id="main_ul">
    <li id="page1">             
  <section id="before-after">
        </section>
    </li>
    <li id="page2">
        <section id="video">
        </section>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want when I scroll down the first list content hides(goes) up and the second list content shows like it was the background of the first list.

Take a look at this website http://www.hadana.comuf.com/
after I start scrolling the image goes up and the div under it shows.

How to do that in css or jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with html and css, a combination of z-indexing, transparent divs, and fixed position div.

run the code snippet below in full view, a bit rushed but you should get the idea.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: BLUE;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}
.section-one {
  background: RED;
}

.section-two{
  padding-top:200px;  
}
.section-two h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.section-three {
  background: GRAY;
}
.fixed-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-one section">

</div>
<div class="section-two section">
  <h1>THIS IS A TEXT</h1>
</div>
<div class="section-three section">

</div>
<div class="fixed-section">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called **parallax** effect!

There are a lot of jquery Plugins out there with those you can do such fancy stuff :)

Check [this link](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/parallax/) out!

Comment: Thanks FalcoB for your answer, but in the website I mentioned in my question he is not using any jQuery plugins.

Comment: i dont understand.... you wrote ** "How to do that in css or jquery ?" **   and if you mean your example website, he actually IS using jquery.... its just on the bottom of the page and not in the header...

Answer (score 1):

That is my idea...

CSS:

```
#main_ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#main_ul li {
    min-height: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
#main_ul li .content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="main_ul">
    <li id="page1">                                                 
        <div class="content">
            <section></section>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="page2">                             
        <div class="content">
            <section></section>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="page3">                             
        <div class="content">
            <section></section>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var main_ul = $('#main_ul');
var li_elements = main_ul.find("li");
var window_height = $(window).height();

var i = 1000;
$.each(li_elements,function() {
    $(this).height(window_height);
    $(this).find(".content").height(window_height).css("z-index",i--).css("position","fixed");
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    $.each(li_elements, function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if(el.offset().top < scroll_offset) {
            el.find(".content").css("position","absolute");
        } else {
            el.find(".content").css("position","fixed");
        }
    });
});
```