# Images in Background-attachment: fixed and Paragraphs in Position: fixed

Tags: html, css, text, position, fixed

I'm making a one-page website which would contain 5 different images each containing a different text.

Here's an example with 2 images:

```css
.img{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.text {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 520px;
  max-width: 520px;
  position: fixed;
}

.img1{
  background-image: url(https://www.gaincontact.com/files/2016/10/Globelanguageshomepage-1.jpg);
}

.img2{
  background-image: url(http://kubikperspectives.com/1/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="img img1">
  <div class="text">
    <p>My name is…</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img img2">
  <div class="text">
    <p>I have been…</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

One problem is when I go to the next image, the first paragraph remains, and as I have 5 different images each containing a different paragraph, I was hoping that the paragraphs meant for each image would be shown when I go up or down. Do you know what code to use to do that?

Comment: Remove `position: fixed` in the .text class

Comment: Is there another way? Because I'd like to have each text to appear at the same position, which is why I use Position: fixed.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like, when I go down or up to another image, the text meant for that image to show itself in the same fixed centered position (precisely to start being shown when the other image goes past the background color). For example, when I go down from img1 to img2, the text changes from "My name is" to "I have been..." when the bottom of img1 starts crossing the background-color

Comment: I added links for the background images, if it helps understand.

Comment: I think the solution is her on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668461/while-scrolling-the-current-div-goes-up-and-another-div-under-it-under-the-fi

Comment: I can't use jQuery, and I've been just told it would require javascript DOM to make happen what I hope to achieve. So I'm going to learn about DOM. Thank you for trying to help and sorry for the trouble. Nebertheless, if you happen to have an answer involving Javascript, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: In the first answer there's no jquery or javascript. Aniway take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r0f7yqe1/